# Multiple downstream stages to a set of parallel stages

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

In a declarative Jenkins pipeline, I need to introduce a `stage X` as another downstream for multiple upstream stages (B1, B2) which already have their corresponding downstream stages (C1,C2).

The visual representation of existing pipeline is as follows.
[image]

This is described using below declarative pipeline syntax.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('A'){
        ...
        }
        stage('BC'){
            paralle {
                stage('1'){
                    stages {
                        stage('B1'){
                        ...
                        }
                        stage('C1'){
                        ...
                        }
                    }
                }
                stage('2'){
                    stages {
                        stage('B2'){
                        ...
                        }
                        stage('C2'){
                        ...
                        }
                    }   
                }
            }
        }
        stage('D') {
        ...         
        }
    }
}
```

I need to perform certain steps when stages B1 and B2 are complete. This I am planning to achieve by introducing a `stage X` as illustrated below.

[image]

How to add `stage X` in existing pipeline? Is there any other mechanism to execute certain steps after B1 and B2 both are complete and without waiting for stages C1,C2 and D?

Comment: One possible way could be to introduce the stage X outside the `parallel` block after B1 and B2, i.e., at the same level as A and D. Then after X, start another `parallel` block consisting of C1, C2, etc. Now, if you want to end the pipeline execution after X, bypassing C1 and C2 as in your diagram, then introduce appropriate `when` conditional before them.

Comment: A -> B1,B2 - > X -> C1,C2 -> D. Can be a workaround but it will not let C continue if any of the B's are taking time to execute. Rather than introducing X as a stage, can it be achieved with some other pipeline construct?

Comment: I can’t think of anything except that you can write a function with the steps that you want inside X, and then call that function twice - once each within/after B1 and B2. Meanwhile keep this question open for the more knowledgeable members to respond.